# Outputting correct object attribute based on user input from an array of objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, io

I have created an array of objects containing information on the Oscars using a text file with all the category names, winners and nominees (winners appear in nominees list as well).  I now want to be able to ask a user.  Of which category would you like to know the winner?  Once the question is asked it would return the answer.  I can only get it to work on the last object of the array(best visual effects returns gravity).  Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
class AwardCategory 
  attr_accessor :winner, :name, :nominees
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @nominees = []
  end
end 

class Nominee
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name 
  end
end 

file = File.open('oscar_noms.txt', 'r')

oscars = []
begin
  while true do
    award_category = AwardCategory.new(file.readline.downcase)
    award_category.winner = file.readline.downcase

    nominee = Nominee.new(file.readline.downcase)
    award_category.nominees << nominee

    next_nominee = Nominee.new(file.readline.downcase)
    until next_nominee.name == "\n"
      award_category.nominees << next_nominee
      next_nominee = Nominee.new(file.readline.downcase)
    end
    oscars << award_category
  end
rescue EOFError => e
  puts 'rescued'
end

#puts oscars.inspect

#Read input here
puts "What category do you want to know the winner for?"
  answer = gets
  oscars.each 
  if answer.downcase == award_category.name
    puts award_category.winner
  else
    puts "That is not a category"
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That piece of code

```
puts "What category do you want to know the winner for?"
  answer = gets
  oscars.each 
  if answer.downcase == award_category.name
    puts award_category.winner
  else
    puts "That is not a category"
    end
```

Now with correct indentation

```
puts "What category do you want to know the winner for?"
answer = gets
oscars.each 
if answer.downcase == award_category.name
  puts award_category.winner
else
  puts "That is not a category"
end
```

Note that the part below `oscars.each` is not indented, because `each` needs a `do`/`end` block which it will execute once for every element. What you probably want is this

```
puts "What category do you want to know the winner for?"
answer = gets
oscars.each do |award_category|
  if answer.downcase == award_category.name
    puts award_category.winner
  else
    puts "That is not a category"
  end
end
```

Although I suggest you leave off the else, because you will get the message `"That is not a category"` for every answer that did not match. Also, you should use `gets.chomp` to remove the newline from the user input and do `downcase` outside of the `each` loop. As a last note, some of your variables are poorly named. For example, why should a list of award categories be named `oscars`? It should be `award_categories` instead.

Comment: I appreciate the help! The array is called Oscars because it holds the nominees, winners and categories.  I want to eventually set it up to answer any question about the Oscars.